# Should enum never be used in an API?

Tags: c, struct, enums, linker, portability

I am using a C library provided to me already compiled.  I have limited information on the compiler, version, options, etc., used when compiling the library.  The library interface uses `enum` both in structures that are passed and directly as passed parameters.

The question is: how can I assure or establish that when I compile code to use the provided library, that my compiler will use the same size for those `enum`s?  If it does not, the structures won't line up, and the parameter passing may be messed up, e.g. `long` vs. `int`.

My concern stems from the C99 standard, which states that the `enum` type:

> shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned
>   integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall
>   be capable of representing the values of all the members of the
>   enumeration.

As far as I can tell, so long as the largest value fits, the compiler can pick any type it darn well pleases, effectively on a whim, potentially varying not only between compilers, but different versions of the same compiler and/or compiler options.  It could pick 1, 2, 4, or 8-byte representations, resulting in potential incompatibilities in both structures and parameter passing.  (It could also pick signed or unsigned, but I don't see a mechanism for that being a problem in this context.)

Am I missing something here?  If I am not missing something, does this mean that `enum` should never be used in an API?

*Update:*

Yes, I was missing something.  While the language specification doesn't help here, as noted by @Barmar the Application Binary Interface (ABI) does.  Or if it doesn't, then the ABI is deficient.  The [ABI for my system](http://people.freebsd.org/~obrien/amd64-elf-abi.pdf) indeed specifies that an `enum` must be a signed four-byte integer.  If a compiler does not obey that, then it is a bug.  Given a complete ABI and compliant compilers, `enum` *can* be used safely in an API.

Comment: As a compromise, you can only use enums as rvalues when making your own API. In c++11 there are enum classes which allow you to specify explicit base types. If you don't have control over the API, you can still look at the assembly code and then replace enum-typed variables with integers of the appropriate size in the headers by hand.

Comment: Shouldn't this be defined as part of an ABI just like the sizes of `float`, `int` etc?

Comment: So, yes, I _was_ missing something.  The ABI is what specifies, or at least should specify the size of an `enum` on the given environment.

Comment: I've encountered enums in a standard library which all ended with `xxLastValue=-1L; /* force int size */`. Always wondered about that but this would be the reason.

Comment: That last paragraph should be in an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I define an enum that will be used across compilers, I make sure there's an enum entry of the size I desire.  I.E. If I want to force my enum items to be a minimum of 16 bit, I create an `ENUM_FORCE_SIZE_16 = 0xFFFF` item in the enum.  Think of a situation where the (continued)

Comment: ... system DLLs are compiled with one compiler and can be used from other compilers, like msvcrt.dll in Windows.

Comment: @JimR: that is both insufficient and pointless.  Insufficient, since different compilers could make that a two, four, or eight-byte `enum`.  Pointless, since the ABI should assure that `enum` has the same size across compilers.  (Though I don't know if should == will in your case.  Does Windows have a consistent, enforced ABI?)

Comment: @MarkAdler: I tested it on Windows (16bit back in the day) and 32 bit and it worked.  I also remember testing it with the IBM, Borland and Watcom compilers and it worked on Windows and OS/2.  It was so insufficient it worked. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

APIs that use enum are depending on the assumption that the compiler will be consistent, i.e. given the same enum declaration, it will always choose the same underlying type.

While the language standard doesn't specifically require this, it would be quite perverse for a compiler to do anything else.

Furthermore, all compilers for a particular OS need to be consistent with the OS's ABI. Otherwise, you would have far more problems, such as the library using 64-bit `int` while the caller uses 32-bit `int`. Ideally, the ABI should constrain the representation of `enum`s, to ensure compatibility.

More generally, the language specification only ensures compatibility between programs compiled with the same implementation. The ABI ensures compatibility between programs compiled with different implementations.

Comment: And that different compilers are consistent with each other somehow.  It might not be perverse for different compilers to choose different underlying types.

Comment: All compilers for a particular system need to be consistent with that system's ABI.

Comment: Aha!  _That_ answers my question.  I found the [relevant ABI for my system](http://people.freebsd.org/~obrien/amd64-elf-abi.pdf), which indeed specifies a four-byte integer type for `enum`.

Comment: Appendix J.3.9 requires an implementation to document the mapping from enum to int. And the language about compatible types seems to imply that the mapping must be consistent in separately-compiled translation units provided the enum declaration is the same.

Comment: On a side note, it is pretty common for evolving API to add constants to an enum in future versions. While a given enum declaration is guaranteed by ABI to result in a given underlying type, adding an additional constant in your enum MAY change the underlying type for the next version of your library. To avoid future issue, you need to know the underlying type for your ABI, and make sure you don't add constant that are incompatible with the underlying type. If using a C11 compiler, you can help yourself by using _Static_assert, eg: _Static_assert(sizeof(enum_type)==sizeof(int),"Wrong Size!");

Comment: @MarkAdler Aren't there newer versions of that document available (I found 0.99.6 from 2012 https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf ) and it adds a bunch of asterisks to the enum.

Comment: @creanion That's why the footnote specifies how the type gets bumped. This ensures consistency across implementations. The type should only be bumped if the number of enum members exceeds the range of 32-bit signed integers.

Answer (score 3):

From the question:

*The ABI for my system indeed specifies that an enum must be a signed four-byte integer. If a compiler does not obey that, then it is a bug.*

I'm surprised about that. I suspect in reality you're compiler will select a 64-bit (8 byte) size for your enum if you define an enumerated constant with a value larger that 2^32.

On my platforms (MinGW gcc 4.6.2 targeting x86 and gcc 4,.4 on Linux targeting x86_64), the following code says that I get both 4 and 8 byte enums:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { a } foo;
enum { b = 0x123456789 } bar;

int main(void) {
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(foo));
    printf("%lu", sizeof(bar));   
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with `-Wall -std=c99` switches.

I guess you could say that this is a compiler bug. But the alternatives of removing support for enumerated constants larger than 2^32 or always using 8-byte enums both seem undesirable.

Given that these common versions of GCC don't provide a fixed size enum, I think the only safe action **in general** is to not use enums in APIs.

### Further notes for GCC

Compiling with "-pedantic" causes the following warnings to be generated:

```
main.c:4:8: warning: integer constant is too large for 'long' type [-Wlong-long]
main.c:4:12: warning: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of 'int' [-pedantic]
```

The behavior can be tailored via the --short-enums and --no-short-enums switches.

### Results with Visual Studio

Compiling the above code with VS 2008 x86 causes the following warnings:

```
warning C4341: 'b' : signed value is out of range for enum constant
warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
```

And with VS 2013 x86 and x64, just:

```
warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
```

Comment: Interesting.  I get the same result with clang, except no warnings!  (Using `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: I verified that the compiler allows me to put those in a `struct` as well, with no complaints.