# Should an .NET API documentation define/expose the literal (numerical) value of enum members?

Tags: c#, .net, api, documentation

As a Software Developer I want to provide documentation for an API I made (provided as part of a product) so that my customers can effectively use the API without having to  call me late at night.

This API is provided in various forms, including a .NET assembly. The .NET assembly includes enums for outputs (specifically return codes). I see some previous discussion about the merits of this approach: [Should enum never be used in an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20809669/2805559) ... so I'll continue.

For example a request to the server will get a result which is just a number, and in the .NET API this will be returned as a enumerated result - something *like* this:

```
public enum ApiResult {
  /// <summary>
  /// Success
  /// </summary>
  Ok,
  /// <summary>
  /// Input parameter was incorrect
  /// </summary>
  InvalidParameter,
  /// <summary>
  /// The method failed
  /// </summary>
  OperationFailed
}
```

My question is: Should a .NET API document include the enum member and description only? ... or should it also include the literal value of the enum member as well (i.e. what the server sent back)?

I can see this is something of a philosophical question, and I cannot really think of a compelling application in C# where you need to know the literal value of an enum member. Does anyone out there have an example?

Finally I would add we also provide equivalent APIs including OLE/COM where enum members *are* documented including their literal numerical values.

Comment: I often explicitly set ("provide") values, even if I don't "expose" such - the API contract is still through the enum, not the numeric value directly. One reason *I* like to provide an explicit value, is a later code addition won't accidentally change the assigned values (which *are* there, even if they are assigned automatically).

Comment: No, it is already obvious from the "Go To Definition" command.  In general, if you don't like people calling you at inconvenient hours then just give them the source.  Be sure to incorporate the bug fixes they give you back into the trunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to document the numeric values of enumerations internal to the C# code.  To that extent, I agree with @Alexei.

However, the enumeration you describe is not internal to C#.  (It's not internal to your code either, but that's not the important point).  It is part of a network interface, and will be placed into datagrams (TCP?IP packets?)  Network tools such as Wireshark will show the numeric value, so **you should document it**.

The same would be true of numeric values stored in files, and any other enumeration which travels outside the confines of the .NET environment.

Answer (score 2):

If enum is strictly C# than I see no good reason to provide numerical values.

Note that unlike C/C++ in C# underlying type of the enum is well defined by language [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

> default ...`int` ... The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

Following are reasons why you may need to add numerical values (mainly interoperation with other languages):

- enum is set of flags used to describe file or wire format - you don't know what language caller would use so enum may not be available
- API can be used in language that does not support enums or have different way to map names to values
- you rely on some particular values of enums rather than names (hiding such behavior from public API may be better, but sometimes not avoidable).

Note that you need to be very careful with versioning of your enum when creating next version of API - as any constant value may be inlined into code at compile time in the calling code.

Note: This is answer to "Should a .NET API documentation include the enum member and description only?" irrespective if actual C# code uses numeric values or not.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I agree these are good reasons to define specific values. Tends to support my position - for C# itself there is no compelling reason, but for interoperability or external interfacing the numerical values could be useful.

Comment: @user2864740 - I think your comment is about something else... the question stated as "Should a .NET API documentation include the enum member and description only" - I don't see how you would make a distinction between "providing" and "exposing" in case of documentation. Numeric value either present in the API documentation or not (irrespective of how C# code is written)...

Comment: I think the sentiment in the last comment, and edited on the end of the answer, should be made more prominent/focal as it is stronger than (and different from) the current introductory statement(s).

Comment: @user2864740 - there is edit button above :) - I'm happy enough with how it is now... Feel free to change the answer.